# indicator changes state on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

so ive forked this code off code pen which is close enough to what im trying to achieve. https://jsfiddle.net/umarg_/1u53ccpr/  as you can see as you scroll from section to section, the indicators update. what do i have to change in order to make it so that once it goes from section 1 to section 2. only the second bar is highlighted. Example.

Section 1 - first green bar highlighted
*scrolls to section 2*
*first green bar no longer highlighted. second green bar highlights*
Section 2 - second green bar highlighted

i hope that made sense. i wanna stay away from any libraries. Im new to JavaScript and want to be able to do everything in vanilla js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.section').length > 0) {
    $('body').append('<div class="progress-meter"></div>');

    for (var i = 0; i < $('.section').length; i++) {
      $('.progress-meter').append('<div class="indicator' + i + '"></div>');
    }

    var diff = $('.section').eq(0).offset().top;

    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < $('.section').length; i++) {
        var offset = $('.section').eq(i).offset();

        if (offset) {
          var distance = offset.top - diff + 5,
            top = $(document).scrollTop(),
            windowHeight = $(window).height(),
            docHeight = $(document).height();

          if ((distance <= top) || (top + windowHeight == docHeight)) {
            $('.indicator' + i).addClass('reached');
          }
          else if ($('.indicator' + i).hasClass('reached')) {
            $('.indicator' + i).removeClass('reached');
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: If you want to stay away from any libraries why are you using `jQuery`, Umar?

Comment: @andrei-gheorghiu oh my bad, forgive a fellow new comer? any suggestions on how i could figure this out

Comment: I don't blame you, nor have you wronged me, so there's nothing to forgive. It's just that the idea to dismiss everything already done is automatically giving you a disadvantage of about 25 years in web development. You should probably reconsider your position towards libraries. Also, posting jQuery code while declaring you don't want to use any library are conflicting. I'm trying to understand what you want.